# How to cite a magazine published seasonally in APA style with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style, apa7

How do you cite a magazine published seasonally in APA style with biblatex?

Using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=none,sortlocale=auto,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{10.1:15a,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE   = {nonacademic},
  AUTHOR         = {E. M. Puckett},
  TITLE          = {Printing protection for {S}outhwest {V}irginia healthcare professionals},
  JOURNALTITLE   = {Imagine: University Libraries at Virginia Tech Magazine},
  VOLUME         = {1},
  NUMBER         = {2},
  PAGES          = {4--5},
  DATE           = {2020, Fall/Winter}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{10.1:15a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get:

> Puckett, E. M. (n.d.). Printing protection for Southwest Virginia healthcare professionals. *Imagine: University Libraries at Virginia Tech Magazine, 1*(2), 4–5.

There is an explicit example on how to cite the date of works that are published seasonally in APA 7 manual on page 290: "(2020, Spring/Summer)." Thus, the date is supposed to look like this: "(2020, Fall/Winter)."

How do I input the date correctly? Is this implemented in biblatex-apa yet?

Comment: `biblatex` is quite strict in what it can receive in the `date` field, as you see in the output you get, it cannot handle the input you gave it. `year` is a little more tolerating, if I recall. But, as far as I understand, `biblatex-apa`, uses the `issuetitle` field for the purpose you intend, so `date={2020}, issutitle={Fall/Winter},` would be the more semantically correct, imho. But that does not give the output you mentioned from the example.

Comment: Also, `biblatex` format date technically can handle seasons, `date = {2020-23/2020-24},` would correspond to "2020 Autumn to 2020 Winter", but I don't get the expected output using it with `biblatex-apa`. Though `biblatex` itself does document this information be given in the `issue` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in recently released biblatex-apa v9.16

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=none,sortlocale=auto,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{10.1:15a,
        ENTRYSUBTYPE   = {nonacademic},
        AUTHOR         = {E. M. Puckett},
        TITLE          = {Printing protection for {S}outhwest {V}irginia healthcare professionals},
        JOURNALTITLE   = {Imagine: University Libraries at Virginia Tech Magazine},
        VOLUME         = {1},
        NUMBER         = {2},
        PAGES          = {4--5},
        DATE           = {2020-23/2020-24}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    \textcite{10.1:15a}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

> Puckett, E. M. (2020, Autumn/Winter). Printing protection for
> Southwest Virginia healthcare professionals. *Imagine: University
> Libraries at Virginia Tech Magazine, 1*(2), 4–5.